Get WooCommerce Grouped Product ID on add to cart validation
I have 7 simple products grouped into 2 grouped products.
In one grouped-product, I allow any customer to buy without any restriction.
in the other grouped-product, I allow add-to-cart only if the customer added to cart a specific product.
How can I get the grouped-product ID to add a condition?
so far my snippet works on both grouped-products:
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'check_variable_product_in_cart', 10, 3 );
function check_variable_product_in_cart( $passed, $product_id, $quantity ) {
    
    // Check if the product being added is one of the specific products
    $specific_products = array( 8541, 8542, 8543, 8544, 8545, 8546, 15985 ); // Replace with your specific product IDs
    if ( in_array( $product_id, $specific_products ) ) {

        // Check if the variable product is in the cart
        $variable_product_id = 8475; // Replace with your variable product ID
        $found = false;
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
            if ( $cart_item['product_id'] == $variable_product_id ) {
                $found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        // If variable product is not in cart, prevent addition of specific products
        if ( ! $found ) {
            $passed = false;
            $product_name = get_the_title( $product_id );
            wc_add_notice( sprintf( __( 'sorry, you must buy product 8475 first', 'your-theme' ), $product_name ), 'error' );
        }
    }

    return $passed;
}


Assuming that product ID 8475 is the required product to be in cart (and not part of the targeted grouped product).
Try the following (defining below your targeted grouped product ID):
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'check_variable_product_in_cart', 10, 3 );
function check_variable_product_in_cart( $passed, $product_id, $quantity ) {
    $targeted_grouped_product_id = 36; // Define here the related grouped product ID
    $required_product_id_in_cart = 8475; // Replace with your specific product ID (in cart)

    // Check for the gouped product ID
    if ( intval($_POST['add-to-cart']) === $targeted_grouped_product_id ) {
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
            if ( $cart_item['product_id'] == $required_product_id_in_cart ) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        $product = wc_get_product($required_product_id_in_cart);
        wc_clear_notices();
        wc_add_notice( sprintf( __( 'Sorry, the product %s must be added to cart first.', 'woocommerce' ), 
            '<a href="'.$product->get_permalink().'"><strong>"'.$product->get_name().'"</strong></a>' 
        ), 'error' );
        return false;
    }
    return $passed;
}

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

